# How to solve the issue of unfocused Input created dynamically using react-hook-form with yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I created a form and I want that when the user create a field the focus will be on the last one.
In practice what is happening it skips to the input that not created dynamicly and this input get the focus .

Click on the + button and you will see that the textarea got focus :

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-8yxvpn?file=/src/pages/CreateRecipe.jsx)

I want the focus to be on the last dynamically created element, not on the textarea.

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using document.getElementById(lastFields.id).focus() in useEffect

add this:
[image]

update this:
[image]